# How to correct add dll reference "Colorpicker.dll" in a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I'm trying to use "Colorpicker.dll" which was referenced in a book I'm reading, but the statement to include the class in the code behing is shown as:

```
using Microsoft.Samples.CustomControls;
```

But when I try to add this line, after Microsoft. I dont have the option to call Samples.

I have added the Colorpicker.dll file to System32 folder, and included the reference in the project. What else I need to do?

*****Resolved!!

Problem was in the ColorPicker.dll file, I redownloaded it and the reference worked.

Comment: Open the References node in your Visual Studio project, then double click on Colorpicker.dll. It should open the Object Browser, where at the top level you can inspect the contained namespaces.

Comment: When I double click nothing happens. Maybe VS is not recognizing the reference? Is there a way to check that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Project > Add Reference…
2. Browse to the .dll to be used and add it.
3. In the .xaml file for the application that is going to use the control, add a reference to the namespace of the control and to its assembly like this: `<xmlns:local3=”clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.CustomControls;assembly=ColorPicker” />` Both of these items will have to be provided in order to use the control.
4. Refer to the UserControl in your xaml file with the local tag:
5. If you add an x:Name attribute to the control in the .xaml, you can reference it in the .cs file.

Found at: [dotupdate.wordpress.com](http://dotupdate.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/using-custom-controls-in-wpf-applications/)

Comment: Already did that, didn't work. Still cannot call:    using Microsoft.Samples.CustomControls;

Comment: Try typing a Class from that dll in your code. Then press right mouse Button on that and see if there is a option "Resolve" or something like that. (Sorry for my first answer, I overlooked that you already added the reference)

Comment: Only generate class is available. I think the main problem is how to correctly call the class in the "using" statement, which I is not being recognized also.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the assembly to the xaml? (See my updated answer)

Comment: Already tried to include the control in the XAML code (but I asked specifically for the code behind call) and it didn't work.